# How to call the ViewModel in the Command properly with the Mef container?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, import, constructor, mef

I want to call the "MainViewModel" in my Command and i wanted to ask how do i call it correctly.

This is my Mef-Container class:

```
public static class MefComponent
    {

        private static CompositionContainer compositionContainer;

        public static T GetImplementationOf<T>()
        {
            try
            {
                return CompositionContainer.GetExportedValue<T>();
            }
            catch (ImportCardinalityMismatchException)
            {
                throw new ImportCardinalityMismatchException();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }

        public static void InitCompositionContainer(object component)
        {
            try
            {
                AggregateCatalog aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
                aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(App).Assembly));
                compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);
                compositionContainer.ComposeParts(component);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public static CompositionContainer CompositionContainer
        {
            get
            {
                return compositionContainer;
            }
        }
    }
```

I wanted to call the ViewModel with the "ImportingConstructor" attribute in the constructor in my command class but that didnt worked well. (Im calling the Command in the constructor in my view model like: CommandXY = MefComponent.GetImplementationOf();)

How can I call the ViewModel in other ways?

Thanks already for the answers!!!!

When i called the viewmodel I got an internal error in my exception message.

My thought about this is following:
When im calling the command through the mef container, the constructor gets called in there, i want the Viewmodel, an it goes back to the viewmodel constructor, it wants to call the command constructor and so on...

Comment: You must declare the dependency as constructor parameter. Then configure your container properly and register all types that participate in the dependency graph. Do not pass around the container! This is a serious code smell and anti-pattern. The container is only referenced once to build the dependency graph. The purpose of an IoC framework is that you define the dependencies as constructor parameter and let the container wire the types up for you. If you need to create types dynamically (during runtime) define and inject an abstract factory.

Comment: Ensure that the instance of MainViewModel is shared across the application (configure the lifetime properly). And don't `throw new MyException` exception. This deletes the call stack. To re-throw simply write `throw;`. If you need to throw a new exception than at least preserve the original call stack by wrapping the original exception into the new exception (as inner exception). You do this by calling the appropriate constructor overload that takes an exception as argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already declared the dependency as constructor Parameter. But it throws anyways the exception :(  In my case im abusing the Mef-Container, but the "throw;" part is a nice advise!!!!!

Comment: Please post the exception message. You probably forgot to register some dependencies. The message will provide the required information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved the problem.

I had to load the class lazy!